# How can I reorder triggered abilities in Arena?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-arena

Suppose I have [Goreclaw, Terror of Qal Sisma](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGoreclaw%2c%20Terror%20of%20Qal%20Sisma%5d) and [Bishop of Binding](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBishop%20of%20Binding%5d) in play. When my creatures attack, I want the Bishop's ability to resolve first (targetting himself), so that he's big enough to get Goreclaw's bonus.

How do I make that happen in Arena? The Oracle rulings on Goreclaw seem to say it's possible ("If another creature has an ability that changes its power when it attacks […] you may have that ability resolve before Goreclaw’s last ability."), but I haven't figured out how to actually accomplish it.

Comment: Daily reminder that questions about Arena are on-topic, even if they are about something technical that is specific to the Arena client.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can enable or disable automatic ordering of triggered abilities and other decisions in the Options -> Gameplay menu, available through the gear symbol in game and out of game.

[image: Gameplay options menu]